Storing and Retrieving Fabric.js Projects
Details: We've integrated Fabric.js with React to allow drawing on the canvas. However, we now face a challenge in persisting canvas data in a database and retrieving it while retaining custom attributes and event listeners for elements.
.
Tried and expecting: Storing the entire canvas object and fetching it for rendering on project opening. While we were able to render objects on the canvas, we couldn't retrieve custom attributes or event listeners associated with them.
We're seeking guidance on how to effectively store and retrieve Fabric.js projects with custom attributes and event listeners intact. Any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this would be greatly appreciated

This is kind of broad. Can you show some example code of what you're trying to do? What event listeners do you have set up exactly? Wanting to serialize event listeners is a bit odd, probably there's a more direct approach to solve whatever problem you have. Thanks.

I tried to apply the same thing as you to my project, but ended up using the method of saving and loading the canvas object and registering an event listener at the same time.
Assuming that the canvas object has been saved and loaded, you can immediately register an event listener as shown below.
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(/* your canvas object parameter */);

// This is a function that registers a listener for canvas.
const addCanvasEvent = () => {
  // ... your codes
};

// This is a function that loads and initializes the canvas.
const loadCanvasObject = (canvasObject) => {
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(canvasObject), () => {
    addCanvasEvent();
  });
};

I hope this helped answer your question. If anyone has a better solution, please share it. Thank you :)
